# Intuition behind the internal operation of the LSTM network

Tags: python, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to find an intuitive explanation for the operation of the LSTM RNN. I have found many papers and tutorials that describe the architecture and the equations for the operation of the LSTM and also a number of "hand-waving" descriptions of how the gates can add or forget elements stored in the "cell memory". What I was hoping to find was a clear description of how the network is trained in a manner that illustrates how the various gates can be controlled.

To make this a proper question, there are two quotes from two sources that use phrases to me that just add to my confusion, so if I may take a slight digression to describe these, and then pose the questions that are puzzling me.

In the first example, which is an excellent and well cited essay on the operation of the LSTM ([See here](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/)) there is a paragraph that reads:

> "Let’s go back to our example of a language model trying to predict
> the next word based on all the previous ones. In such a problem, the
> cell state might include the gender of the present subject, so that
> the correct pronouns can be used. When we see a new subject, we want
> to forget the gender of the old subject."

And in the second example from an equally good paper ([Reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02078) ) exploring the inner operations of the LSTM network there is a sentence:

> "The LSTM could conceivably store a summary of previously seen
> characters in the data and fall back on this memory when it is
> uncertain."

So my questions relating to these two examples are as follows.

First, relating to the first example, it implies that the LSTM is aware of a subject and that the subject has a gender such that when a new subject appears the gender has to change. So the question is, how can the network be aware of what is the subject, that it has a gender, and that the subject has changed. Is this something that is pushed in during the training phase?

In the second example, it sounds like the operation of the network is opaque at best, (which I accept was part of the purpose of that paper to explain some of these unknowns). So my second questions, is the quest to understand the inner operation of the LSTM a pointless task, and to just rely on the "hand-waving" explanations for its operation?

And my final question, if the statement "There is a no real understanding surrounding the internal operation of the LSTM." is incorrect, are there any papers or tutorials that provide a more tangible explanation on how the training of the LSTM is used to control the various gates within its architecture.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: refer [this](https://youtu.be/WCUNPb-5EYI) video